# I just moved entire website to a new server, but am still getting traffic to my old one (caching issue?)

Tags: dns

I just sold a website, so I transferred everything to new owners' server. The name servers are now pointing to his server as well. I also replaced all of my Adsense tags with the buyers'. However, I'm still getting a small number of daily Adsense views to all of my tags even though none of them are on the site anymore (1,000 page views per day or so).

My question is this: is there a caching issue here or something? Are DNS providers not honoring the new server location and will it just take time for this issue to go away?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It can take 24-48 and sometimes 72 hours to propagate through all of the DNS servers though generally, it really should not take that long. You can check the TTL of the domain name though this is not an indication of propagation, it can slow things down if it a large number. The TTL is a number of seconds before cache expires. How long has it been? I also advise double and triple-checking your work for small errors that have been missed. You can use Google Analytics and AdSense to see if there is a/are common page(s).

Comment: Adding to @closetnoc check your A record has propagated fully. I use this all the time: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: That is an interesting website. It cannot check all the DNS servers in the world. It appears to be checking some of the bigger DNS servers. Generally, the major DNS servers will propagate fast. It is the smaller ISPs that might be looking to shave some traffic and not update as quickly as they should. *Check the Google products to see if there are any clues.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the [comment by closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72668/i-just-moved-entire-website-to-a-new-server-but-am-still-getting-traffic-to-my#comment83030_72668), its most likely a DNS issue. As he says it can take up to 48+ hours for all the ISP's like mobile internet and cable modems to "catch up". Generally the server to server traffic is quicker, more like 1-8 hours.

In interest of this question, here are a couple tips for this transfer situation and how to poke your ISP/Cache to get new site faster:

-- If youre planning to transfer, hit your domain zones and check the TTL. 2 days before transfer, make it low like 120 seconds. Turn off non-essential caches. Prepare querystring cachebuster for things like css/js/font assets. Basically, make a bunch of things "call home" more often. More likely to freshen client DNS and see new stuff after transfer. A couple days after things settle, turn back on the caches, remove the cachebusters, and increase the TTL to whatever it was.

-- In addition to DNS check sites, a way to browse your transfered site the fastest often comes in the form of a webproxy like [proxfree.com](http://proxfree.com) or similar. You want to test with one that preferably has never accessed your site. Obviously don't use any admin areas or enter passwords while using these proxies, but they offer a fresh window to confirm it's online via new DNS.

-- If you are having trouble viewing the new version of your site, you can try to clear your OS & Browser side DNS cache. With Chrome that is easy, paste `chrome://net-internals/#dns` in the address bar and hit "clear host cache". With Windows its kinda easy too, open "run" box and use command `ipconfig /flushdns` then restart Chrome. Don't forget about `shift-F5` in browsers too which forces a refresh.

Hope that helps clarify the spots DNS would hang up while propagating your new site location.